# Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'. flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

Out of nowhere this problem came.

> Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'. flutter

I was trying to execute code from the emulator suddenly this problem occur Now what is the solution of this problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.